# SQLIte3 querying a database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm trying to write a program to query a database. The database is golfDB and it consists of one table called `players` with 5 fields:

- `name` (player's name)
- `totalGross` (sum of the gross scores from each round)
- `totalRounds` (number of rounds played)
- `pars` (total number of pars made)
- `birdies` (total number of birdies made)

My program needs to output the player with the most pars, the average score (totalGross/ totalRounds) for an inputed player, and to list the players in order of total gross score, lowest to highest.

I'm really not sure how to output the player with the most pars.  Right now the code I have is outputting a list of lists, each with a player and their pars.  I'm not sure how to order them by their pars and then select the highest ones because everything I've tried is just selecting the numbers out and then I cannot get back to which player they belong to.

Does anyone know how to order the list of lists by just the number of pars and then it can just print the player?

```
import sqlite3

def getDBCursor(DB):
    """obtain and return a cursor for the database DB"""
    conn= sqlite3.connect('/Users/tinydancer9454/Documents/python/golfDB')
    cursor= conn.cursor()
    return cursor

def queryDBpars(cursor):
    """find out which player had the most pars"""
    cursor.execute('select name, pars from players where pars >= 0')
    playerPars= cursor.fetchall()


def queryDBavgScore(cursor):
    """find the average score of inputed player"""
    player= input("Please enter the player's name: ")
    cursor.execute('select totalGross from players where name = ?', (player,))
    totalGrossScore = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.execute('select totalRounds from players where name = ?', (player,))
    totalRoundsScore = cursor.fetchone()
    answer = totalGrossScore[0]/ totalRoundsScore[0]
    print('The average score for', player, 'is', answer,)

def queryDBplayers(cursor):
    """lists the players in order of their total gross score"""


def main():
    """obtain cursor and query the database: golfDB"""
    cursor= getDBCursor('golfDB')
    queryDBpars(cursor)
    queryDBavgScore(cursor)
    queryDBplayers(cursor)
    cursor.close()
```

And this is the output:

```
[('Ruth', 16), ('Elena', 12), ('Jane', 12), ('Ezgi', 13), ('Ricki', 9), ('Margaret', 10), ('Rosalia', 16), ('Betty', 14)]
```

Comment: try this query:select * from players where pars >= 0 order by pars desc limit 1

Comment: @varahram if you limit it to 1, it doesn't take into account the fact that more than one player could have the same amount of pars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple SQL question. For the straight answer to your question, you just need:

```
SELECT name, pars FROM players WHERE pars >= 0 ORDER BY pars DESC
```

But that still leaves you selecting all the players where you don't need to. To prevent that, just add a LIMIT clause:

```
SELECT name, pars FROM players WHERE pars >= 0 ORDER BY pars DESC LIMIT 1
```

and you would then use `cursor.fetchone()` to get just that single row.

**Edit**

You say that there could be more than one person with the most pars. That makes the query significantly more complex: now we're into subqueries:

```
SELECT name, pars FROM players WHERE pars >= 0 WHERE pars = (
    SELECT MAX(pars) FROM players)
```

So what this is doing is finding the maximum value for 'pars', then selecting the rows that have this value.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about the LIMIT command.  However the only problem with this is that there could be more than one player with the same number of pars.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) SQL keyword in your query, or if you want to do it in python you can do it a couple of ways:

```
def queryPars(cursor):
    """find out which player had the most pars"""
    cursor.execute('select pars, name from players where pars >= 0')
    ## Note flipped order ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    playerPars = cursor.fetchall()
    pars, player_most_pars = max(playerPars)
    # Now do something useful with it ;-)
```

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) describe how tuples are compared. (Basically, entry by entry). If you cannot change the order of your query, you can also do something like `player, pars = max(playerPars, key=lambda p: p[1])`

Comment: I prefer to use the ORDER BY keyword, but I'm just not sure how to deal with the fact that more than one player could have the same number of pars and therefor both would need to be outputted.

Comment: Use two queries then! First find the minimum number of pars and then `SELECT name FROM players WHERE pars=?`